# Where is pytorch documentation for indexing tensors?

Tags: pytorch

I cannot find documentation for pytorch tensor indexing. For example, I'd like to understand what exactly happens when you take a tensor `t`, a tensor of indices `idx` and try to use them to index `t`, i.e. `t[idx]`. I am not looking just for the explanation of the above, I would like to understand where I can find information on indexing when I need it, which is why I'd prefer a link to documentation.

I found some descriptions in [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html#tensor-operations), but it is clearly far from complete, only showing the most basic indexing techniques.

Comment: You can always check their [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/6718e3ca7cc7a9e5ad13a98033ad25536305a70a/torch/_tensor.py#L81). One thing to note that the inners of pytorch are written in C.

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu, could you then direct me to where exactly the code responsible for indexing is please? The file is over 1000 lines long, it's not really clear how to find the part about indexing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the direct answer for your question but could help. Pytorch tensors are very similar to numpy arrays. If you struggle to find answer for question related to indexing, it's highly probable that you will find it in numpy documentation.

Comment: I thought they are similar, but is there any official guarantee though that indexing on torch tensors is the same as on numpy arrays? That would of course answer my question, because for numpy ample documentation is available.

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html  

_Tensors are similar to NumPy’s ndarrays, except that tensors can run on GPUs or other specialized hardware to accelerate computing. If you’re familiar with ndarrays, you’ll be right at home with the Tensor API. If not, follow along in this quick API walkthrough._  

I guess this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @yep, thank you! So I guess the answer to the question is that there is no docs for torch tensors, instead one should look at numpy array docs.